# Firebase 3 - javascript - get facebook accessToken after login

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

In Firebase 2 I was able to get facebook `accessToken` from anywhere after login by [this](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html#section-logging-in) way, just using the [firebase reference](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-creating-references), eg:

```
firebase.getAuth().facebook.accessToken
```

Now, how can I get that in version 3 (web)?

**Note, I need it outside of the Promise** `signInWithPopup`

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I just found [this](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#get_the_access_token_numbered) on documentation... Why? :(

> Since Firebase Authentication no longer persists the access token,
>   your application will have to do so itself, if needed.

Comment: It looks like this is related to inconsistencies in the auth apis for some of their providers

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear now: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#get_the_access_token "With the Firebase.com Authentication API, you can easily use the provider's access token to call out to the provider's API and get additional information. This access token is still available, but only immediately after the sign-in action has completed."

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {

    // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
})
```

Comment: That's inside the login, what I mean is outside "after login", I'm using AWS cognito and I need that `accessToken` in other side... so I could I get it from other class/method?

Comment: @user2976753 Did you ever find the answer? I'm looking for a solution as well.

Comment: But saving and managing the token yourself is problematic as the Google one (= gapi token) expires after 60 minutes. With new Firebase one would seem to need to fire the login routine (popup) all over again to get to the Google token...
This is the most relevant thread I've found:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387535/how-to-refresh-google-accesstoken-in-firebase-askfirebase

Comment: @VitaliKniazeu But OP is asking about fb login, not google...

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer is to unlink "auth.currentUser.unlink(provider)" the provider and re link "auth.currentUser.linkWithPopup(provider)" each time you need to get the access token.

Comment: Have to use a sign up with credentials as kind of the base case. Then you can link/unlink other providers.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the user access token is to use the `FB API` itself.

Simply follow [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web) guide on how to include it and then get the token the following way:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } 
} );
```