# Using Firebase Auth to access the Google Calendar API

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, google-calendar-api, firebase-authentication

I am building a web application using AngularJS, Firebase (SDK v3) and Google Calendar API. I'm authenticating users using Google OAuth. My purpose is to be able to create calendar events from database nodes in Firebase. So far I've managed to request access to the calendar scope with:

```
_authProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
// Get permission to manage Calendar
_authProvider.addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
_fbAuthObject.signInWithRedirect(_authProvider);
```

I'm authenticating with the redirect flow so the authentication redirect is available as:

```
_fbAuthObject.getRedirectResult()
    .then(function _readToken(result) {
      if (result.credential) {
        _googleToken = result.credential.accessToken;
        var authHeader = 'Bearer '+ _googleToken;

        // Just a test call to the api, returns 200 OK 
        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': authHeader
          },
          url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList/primary'
        })
          .then(function success(response) {
            console.log('Cal response', response);
          },
          function error(response) {
            console.log('Error', response);
          });
```

However, it seems like outside the initial login it's not possible to get the Google access token through the Firebase SDK. It seems only possible to access the Firebase JWT token, no use with the Calendar API. I could store the access token, but this wouldn't resolve the problems when refreshing the token, etc. Is there any way to get the current Google Access token with Firebase SDK and if not, what other solutions is there to the problem without having to authenticate the user twice?

**UPDATE 1:**

Seems like [someone else has struggled with similar problems with Facebook authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372150/firebase-3-javascript-get-facebook-accesstoken-after-login). On that question there was a [link to the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#get_the_access_token_numbered) stating that Firebase Authentication no longer persists the access token. So how can I handle token refreshes? Is there really no answer to this?

**UPDATE 2:**

So, I contacted Firebase Support with a feature request about this problem and they gave me the following answer:

> Thanks for taking your time to write us.
>
> I've got your point here, this is indeed a good suggestion. We're definitely aware that many users, such as yourself, would like OAuth feature that will access token upon refresh. We're exploring potential solutions, but I cannot guarantee if this will be available anytime soon. We'll keep your feedback in consideration moving forward though. Continuous improvement is very important for our community, so thanks for bringing this up!
>
> Keep an eye out on our release notes for any further updates.

So It seems like the access tokens are not available through the Firebase SDK at the moment. I'm still trying to find a workaround, so if anyone has ideas about a valid solution I'd be glad to hear them. And of course, I'll be posting it here if I ever find a working solution myself.

Comment: I believe the details should be added to the currentUser object, have you tried checking what exists in the current user object? `firebase.auth().currentUser;` https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: Yes, but I can't seem to find the Google tokens from there. I've also tried the getToken() function, but the Firebase JWT token can't be used with the Google APIs.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182671/is-it-possible-to-add-events-to-a-users-google-calendar-via-firebase-server-sid/49183647#49183647

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally got around this problem by handling the authentication outside Firebase with the Google APIs JavaScript client. This solution requires including the Google auth client as [documented here](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/cors.md#loading-the-standalone-auth-client). Manually handling the Firebase sign-in flow is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#advanced-handle-the-sign-in-flow-manually).

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()
    .then(function _firebaseSignIn(googleUser) {
      var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
        unsubscribe();
        // Check if we are already signed-in Firebase with the correct user.
        if (!_isUserEqual(googleUser, firebaseUser)) {
          // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
          var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
            googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);

          // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
          return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
            .then(function(result) {
              // other stuff...
            });
```

The _isUserEqual function:

```
function _isUserEqual(googleUser, firebaseUser) {
  if (firebaseUser) {
    var providerData = firebaseUser.providerData;
    for (var i = 0; i < providerData.length; i++) {
      if (providerData[i].providerId === firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID &&
        providerData[i].uid === googleUser.getBasicProfile().getId()) {
        // We don't need to reauth the Firebase connection.
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Now I can reference the access token like this:

```
var user = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get();
return user.getAuthResponse().access_token;
```

This still isn't the ideal solution for me, but it works for now, and I'm able to authenticate to both Firebase and the Calendar API.

Comment: Oh gosh!! I just want to kiss you right now! Thanks for this live saving answer!