# AngularFire2 - using access token from Google Auth for Google APIs

Tags: angularjs, angular, authentication, firebase, angularfire2

Google Authentication through AngularFire2 returns the Firebase access token, but *not* the Google access token for use on Google APIs.  What's the proper way to get the access token from the AngularFire2 auth?

Angular: 2.4.9

Firebase: 3.5.2

AngularFire: 2.0.0-beta.8

Here's a plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/qIbtcp?p=preview

You'll notice in the constructor:

```
constructor(af: AngularFire, public auth$: AngularFireAuth, public http:Http) {

      auth$.subscribe((state: FirebaseAuthState) => {
        if(state){
          this.signedIn = true
        }
    });

    firebase.auth()
      .getRedirectResult()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('result', result);
        if (result.credential) {
          // This gives you a Google Access Token.
          var token = result.credential.accessToken;
          console.log('token',token)
          this.getPeople(token)
          .subscribe(
            people => console.log('people',people),
            error =>  console.log(error)); 
        }
        var user = result.user;
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

Where I call firebase.auth() is where I try to get the Google Access Token.  However on first login, I get this error:

```
{
error: {
code: 403,
message: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
}
```

I know this *shouldn't* happen because I tried the same setup with strictly Firebase (no AngularFire2), in this example:

https://embed.plnkr.co/zxOfRZ1PDDb7ee5qzIKW/

So is there an issue with sharing auth tokens between AngularFire and just Firebase?  Does anyone have an example of this working?

Comment: You're subscribing in two places with two different kinds of tokens. `result.credential.accessToken` is the correct one and I'd expect that to work fine. But you can't use `auth.getToken()`, which returns a Firebase ID token (not a Google access token).

Comment: @Kato sorry I should have made the code more clear, I took out the auth.getToken() - I do use ```result.credential.accessToken```, but it results in a a 403 permission denied "request had insufficient authentication scopes", despite my app having accepted the scopes (from the AngularAuth login with method:redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a similar issue on StackOverflow:

[Using Firebase Auth to access the Google Calendar API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914899/using-firebase-auth-to-access-the-google-calendar-api)

I ended up using the same approach, it seems that you need to manually use the Google API's Javascript client, and use that credential to sign in with Firebase.