# how to get a new acces token to interact with Google Api with firebase authentication in angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-authentication

users log into my angular application via firebasebase provider.

```
new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
```

successively

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()
```

When the application accesses I only have a token like

> ya29.a0AfH6SMAYg1A1RLwrEGe19qozweR9AFXuLJwSHb4FzQvuXk-ObVa54mpErd09mb4G3***********

that expires after a short time.
How do I increase the deadline time as the [official google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#5.-refresh-the-access-token,-if-necessary.) says?

**Update**

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {

 if (result.credential) {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  }
  var user = result.user;
});
```

I would like to get this `token` but with extended expiration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

**Step 1**: 
i have installed [ng-gapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-gapi) in my angular project. (and configured it)

**Step 2**: 
through google ng-gapi i logged in

```
 this.gapiService.getAuth()
  .subscribe((auth) => {
    auth.signIn().then(res => this.signInSuccessHandler(res));
  });
```

**Step 3**:
i login in firebase mannualy as  [documentation said](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#advanced:-handle-the-sign-in-flow-manually)

**Step 4**:
now through ng-gapi i can get the token

```
this.gapiService.getAuth().subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x.Od.$B);
});
```

(i don't know if exist a poper function to get `x.Od.$B` but it's work)

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar question here :

[Using Firebase Auth to access the Google Calendar API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914899/using-firebase-auth-to-access-the-google-calendar-api)

it seems the only to go is to use the Google APIs JS for Authentication